# Counting phrase frequency in Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, frequency, phrase

I have been examining different sources on the web and have tried various methods but could only find how to count the frequency of unique words but not unique phrases. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import collections
import re
wanted = set(['inflation', 'gold', 'bank'])
cnt = collections.Counter()
words = re.findall('\w+', open('02.2003.BenBernanke.txt').read().lower())
for word in words:
    if word in wanted:
        cnt [word] += 1
print (cnt)
```

If possible, I would also like to count the number of times the phrases 'central bank' and 'high inflation' is used in this text. I appreciate any suggestion or guidance you can give.

Comment: do you want to find frequencies of [words bigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) in a text?

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian, in a way, but specific ones, like the frequency of a phrase such as "high inflation rate."

Comment: related: [What are ngram counts and how to implement using nltk?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12821201/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is how I would generate the `cnt` that you do (to reduce memory overhead)

```
def findWords(filepath):
  with open(filepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
      words = re.findall('\w+', line.lower())
      yield from words

cnt = collections.Counter(findWords('02.2003.BenBernanke.txt'))
```

Now, on to your question about phrases:

```
from itertools import tee
phrases = {'central bank', 'high inflation'}
fw1, fw2 = tee(findWords('02.2003.BenBernanke.txt'))   
next(fw2)
for w1,w2 in zip(fw1, fw2)):
  phrase = ' '.join([w1, w2])
  if phrase in phrases:
    cnt[phrase] += 1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In python 3.3, you can use `yield from`.

Comment: `phrase` become `True` or `False`. So `phrase in phrases` always yields False.

Comment: This code does not yields what OP wants. Try the code with `the central bank high inflation` as contents of the file and with `central bank high inflation`. You may need to use something like `itertools.tee`. See `pairwise` recipe from [`itertools recipes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: @falsetru: thanks for the bug report and the "`yield from`" comment. Please let me know if the changes help

Comment: You're treating the first and second words as a phrase, and the third and fourth etc, but not the second and third

Comment: @gnibbler: you're right! How did I miss that?! It's fixed now

Comment: Now you're processing the file twice. Let me edit it to use `tee`

Comment: Hey you guys, thanks for the quick responses. The code so far, however, counts the frequencies of all words and not of the phrases. I've checked, and its based on the first set of code:                             def findWords(filepath):
  with open(filepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
      words = re.findall('\w+', line.lower())
      yield from words

cnt = collections.Counter(findWords('02.2003.BenBernanke.txt'))        I'll try and see if an edit for that one works for the specific words

Comment: @Raul: there's two snippets of code. The second one deals with phrases

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, but the second snippet depends on the first and for some reason, it still registers only words, not phrases. is it perhaps a glitch on the 3.3.2 version?

Comment: @Raul: are you sure? The second snippet should do both words and phrases

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Unfortunately, yes, I've connected it to the first snippet and it returns the frequency of all the words in the text file. Is there a way to isolate the result to just the phrases? Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: @Raul: yeah, just replace `cnt = ...` with `cnt = collections.Counter()` in the first snippet

Answer (score 1):

To count literal occurrences of couple of phrases in a small file:

```
with open("input_text.txt") as file:
    text = file.read()
n = text.count("high inflation rate")
```

There is [`nltk.collocations`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=collocation#module-nltk.collocations) module that provides tools to identify  words that often appear consecutively:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder, TrigramCollocationFinder

# run nltk.download() if there are files missing
words = [word.casefold() for sentence in sent_tokenize(text)
         for word in word_tokenize(sentence)]
words_fd = nltk.FreqDist(words)
bigram_fd = nltk.FreqDist(nltk.bigrams(words))
finder = BigramCollocationFinder(word_fd, bigram_fd)
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
print(finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 5))
print(finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq))

# finder can be constructed from words directly
finder = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
# filter words
finder.apply_word_filter(lambda w: w not in wanted)
# top n results
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
print(sorted(finder.nbest(trigram_measures.raw_freq, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is not huge - this is the easiest way

```
for w1, w2 in zip(words, words[1:]):
    phrase = w1 + " " + w2
    if phrase in wanted:
        cnt[phrase] += 1
print(cnt)
```

Comment: Hey gnibbler, thanks for all of the great insight! however, when I incorporate this part of the code with the first snippet above, it returns an error message indicating that 'words' is not recognized. Do you happen to know why that is? Thanks again for all of the help.

Comment: `words` is just the list of words from your question. The `for` loop combines pairs of words to create (two word) phrases