# Python Count Number of Phrases in Text

Tags: python, pandas, text-classification

I have a list of product reviews/descriptions in excel and I am trying to classify them using Python based on words that appear in the reviews.

I import both the reviews, and a list of words that would indicate the product falling into a certain classification, into Python using Pandas and then count the number of occurrences of the classification words.

This all works fine for single classification words e.g. 'computer' but I am struggling to make it work for phrases e.g. 'laptop case'.

I have look through a few answers but none were successful for me including:

using just `text.count(['laptop case', 'laptop bag'])` as per the answer here: [Counting phrase frequency in Python 3.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920572/counting-phrase-frequency-in-python-3-3-2) but because you need to split the text up that does not work (and I think maybe text.count does not work for lists either?)

Other answers I have found only look at the occurrence of a single word. Is there something I can do to count words and phrases that does not involve the splitting of the body of text into individual words?

The code I currently have (that works for individual terms) is:

```
for i in df1.index:
    descriptions = df1['detaileddescription'][i]
    if type(descriptions) is str:
        descriptions = descriptions.split()
        pool.append(sum(map(descriptions.count, df2['laptop_bag'])))
    else:
        pool.append(0)
print(pool)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right track! You're currently splitting into single words, which facilitates finding occurrences of single words as you pointed out. To find phrases of length `n` you should split the text into chunks of length `n`, which are called `n-grams`.

To do that, check out the [NLTK package](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html):

```
from nltk import ngrams
sentence = 'I have a laptop case and a laptop bag'
n = 2
bigrams = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)
for gram in bigrams:
    print(gram)
```

Comment: You also might want to look into the Spacy library, which has n-gram tokenizers as well, and has been fun to work with in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) is the standard way

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
vectorizer = text.CountVectorizer()
vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(descriptions)
```

And if you want to see the counts as a `dict`:

```
count_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), vec.toarray()[0]) if v>0}
print (count_dict)
```

The default is unigrams, you can use bigrams or higher ngrams with the `ngram_range` parameter