# Create Matrix of word's count for multiple sentences using Ngram-Python

Tags: python, matrix, n-gram

Let's say I have multiple sentences(Not a paragraph) like Sentence A,B,C and so on in a csv file. And I want to calculate the matrix of words in each sentence using N-gram(Unigrams or Bigrams). So that I can get a calculated N-gram vector for each sentence from my Matrix easily. How do I do it?

PS:I have tried several methods but all of them calculate N-gram for either a sentence or a whole paragraph!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are ngram counts and how to implement using nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821201/what-are-ngram-counts-and-how-to-implement-using-nltk)

Comment: @YuvalRaz The question that has been answered in the link is different from mine :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try using a pandas data frame and use "apply" on every row

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv("the_santances.csv")

x.apply("the function that calculates the ngram")
```